# Bugzilla error after installation

Tags: ubuntu, bugzilla

After the installation of bugzilla, I am unable to find the bugzilla login page, The following are the errors which is showing in the browser.

./data/params file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 337.

Compilation failed in require at /var/www/bigbugz/bugz/index.cgi line 34.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/bigbugz/bugz/index.cgi line 34.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `checksetup.pl`.

Comment: Did it, It shows a list of packages that needs to be installed. But I have already installed those packages.

Answer (score 0):

(It appears I don't have permission to post replies.)

If Bugzilla tells you you need to install the packages, then it can't find them. So you may have a Perl library path problem. The simple fix is to run the commands it tells you, in order to install your own local copies in the Bugzilla lib/ directory. If you definitely want to use the system versions, then you'll have to work out what's wrong with the path.

Note also that Bugzilla requires certain versions of packages - installing "CGI" is not enough, we need a very recent version. Check the output to see whether Bugzilla can't in fact find the packages, or whether it's finding them but the version is too old.

Gerv